# Misleading message is given when flagging with 0 remaining question flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, error-message

I have searched extensively for this, and am surprised it's not already raised.

When you have 0 question flags remaining,  clicking "flag", then selecting a flag option (not the "Other" flag), and then clicking the "Flag Question" button, returns the following message in a red box:

> You can only flag for moderator attention 23 times per day

(23 is my total, yours depends on your rep, total good flags etc)

I didn't attempt for *moderator* attention, I flagged for *community* to review in the review queue.

While the total flags you have remaining is quite visible, some users might not pay attention to how many flags they have remaining. So when using a flag other than "Other", such as "unclear what you are asking", the message about "Moderator attention" is misleading.

Propose the message is changed to something like:

> You have used up your X flags for today

---

**NOTE:**

I do not know what happens when one has 0 flags remaining and the "Other" flag is used. I didn't test this incase it worked and wasted mod time etc.

---

---

**EDIT:**

I've also just noticed in the flag-summary page, it states under "Your flagging history":
"*X moderator attention flags*"
However these are for the normal flags too - not just moderator, and this is especially confusing with the word "attention" as the "Other" flag does state "moderator attention".

Suggest dropping the words "moderator attention", and just have something like "X total flags" - this will work in line with the above proposal to change the warning message.

Comment: The warning is indeed misleading. I think using a single message for flagging indicating that you're out of flags is appropriate. the interpretation of the current message appears to indicate an excess of moderator flagging, as opposed to an excess of general flagging.

Comment: Not X total flags. X post flags. Comment flags (which are usually handled by moderators) don't count there.

Comment: Yeah I've always wondered about this. "Moderator attention" indicates you raised a moderator flag, though those messages seem to be around for regular review queue questions too. Perhaps one of the StackOverflow elders will know for sure, but my guess is that the message is a remnant of what flagging was from before community review queues.